# Merging a list of maps (of list of string)

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming

Baby Kotlin dev here :)

Considering the following structure:

```
[
  { "color": ["red", "blue"] },
  { "color": ["red", "green"] },
  { "shape": ["square", "circle"] },
  { "shape": ["rectangle"] }
]
```

I'd like to obtain the following results where keys and their respective values are merged:

```
[
  { "color": ["red", "blue", "green"] },
  { "shape": ["square", "circle", "rectangle"] }
]
```

After some research I was thinking of something like this (doesn't work/compile), but I'm missing some pieces:

```
val colors1 = mapOf("color" to listOf("red", "blue"))
val colors2 = mapOf("color" to listOf("red", "green"))
val shapes1 = mapOf("color" to listOf("square", "circle"))
val shapes2 = mapOf("color" to listOf("rectangle"))
var mainList = mutableListOf(colors1, colors2, shapes1, shapes2)

mainList.reduce { acc, it -> (acc.asSequence() + it.asSequence())
    .distinct()
    .groupBy({it.key}, {it.value})
    .mapValues { (_, values) -> values.flatten().distinct() }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of merging the maps with `reduce`, you can use `flatMap` with the map `entries`. So it should work this way:

```
mainList
    .flatMap { it.entries }
    .groupBy({ it.key }, { it.value })
    .mapValues { (_, values) -> values.flatten().toSet() }
```

<sup>[(runnable sample)](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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)</sup>

Also, a little bit more efficient way to flatten the values in the last line is:

```
    .mapValues { (_, values) -> values.flatMapTo(mutableSetOf()) { it } }
```

This removes the overhead of the intermediate collection that was created to store the values between `flatten()` and `distinct()`/`toSet()`, but still ensures that the items are unique because they are added to a `mutableSet()`.

---

Sample with reassigning the `mainList`: [(link)](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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)

Comment: Makes sense! But what if I need to assign back to `mainList`? `toList()` seems to change the inner structure of the list:
`Kotlin: Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is Map<String, Set<String>> but MutableList<Map<String, List<String>>> was expected`

Comment: @aaaaahaaaaa, then you need to change two things: wrap the whole expression into a `mutableListOf(...)` (by the way, do you need it to be mutable?), and ensure that the value type of the inner maps is a `List` – here, your approach with `.flatten().distinct()` should work. See the link in the end of the answer that I've jsut added.

Comment: ```mutableListOf(mainList.flatMap { it.entries }
      .groupBy({ it.key }, { it.value })
      .mapValues { (_, values) -> values.flatten().distinct().toList() })```
is what I need to assign it back!

Comment: Actually I just realised it doesn't fit my original requirement because I end up with a single map inside the main list, instead of two separate maps.